# Why does Express look for static files in wrong location when url path is more than two levels deep?

Tags: node.js, express

The Express version is the latest.

This is the app.js file, which is used by another app.js file:

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express'), engine = require('ejs-locals');
var path = require('path'), map = require('../../app').map;
var register = require('./routes/register').register;   
var profile = require('./routes/profile').profile;      
var login = require('./routes/login').login;            

var app = module.exports = express();
app.configure(function() {
    app.engine('ejs', engine);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
});

app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.map = map;
app.map(app, {
    '/seller': {
        '/password': {
            get: login.forgot, // Looks in the correct place /assets/css/... etc.
            '/forgot': {
                get: login.forgot // Looks in wrong place /seller/assets/... etc.
            },
            '/reset': {
                get: login.reset
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When GET `http://localhost:3000/seller/password` is requested, Express looks for the static files in the correct location, namely ***/assets/css/***.

But when GET `http://localhost:3000/seller/password/forgot` is requested, Express looks for the static files in the wrong place, namely ***/seller/assets/css***, which does not even exist.

This is the map function. It is taken from the Express [route-map example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-map/index.js).

```
function route_map(app, a, route) {
    route = route || '';
    for (var key in a) {
        switch (typeof a[key]) {
            case 'object': // { '/path': { ... }}
            app.map(app, a[key], route + key);
            break;
            case 'function': // get: function(){ ... }
            app[key](route, a[key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt look right to me, the nesting at `/password` may should have a subroute `/` for the root?

Comment: I fixed the indentation.

Comment: No i thought more about something like : http://jsfiddle.net/z87eE/

Comment: Oh, but that is not necessary. It maps the url without the explicit root.

Comment: Does it help when you move `app.use('/assets', express.static...)` to below `app.map()`?

Comment: No, it does not. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What exactly does the `map` function do? How does it work?

Comment: @GoloRoden, I added the map function.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is express looking for the static files referenced in your template in the wrong directory? What does the url look like in the case when it's working and in the case when it's not?

Comment: @AndreasHultgren, Yes. I have updated my question with the full url.

Comment: Can you show me your login function?

Comment: How do you actually know where Express is trying to find the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing requesting *wrong* file should be browser, not express, express is a server. So your client side html might be wrong, probably it tries to go `../../assets/css` which is correct when your URL is `/seller/password/` because it has 2 levels and your css request has 2 up-directories but, when your URL is is `/seller/password/forgot` it tries to go 2-levels up and it is now at `/seller` so it appends the `/assets/css` after that.

Comment: Yes, in the layout I had `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. I removed the dot-dot.